# Work with image picked by File Picker in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to workk with an image picked by file picker in windows phone 8.1.I picked an image using this code

```
  private async void gallery_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        // Launch file open picker and caller app is suspended and may be terminated if required
        openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
   }


 public async void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                StorageFile file=args.Files[0];

                IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await                     file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

                bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream);
                MyImage.Source=bitmapImage;

  }
            else
            {

            }
}
```

ContinueFileOpenPicker not executing I tried [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn614994.aspx) but unable to understand that.Can any here guide me step by step what should I do to make it work.Thanks

Comment: Well the article you linked contains step by step guide. It seems like you don't call the continuation code anywhere when the app is resumed.

Comment: can u please post some code

Comment: The article you have linked not only contains code but there is a link to a full sample app.

Answer (score 4):

```
 protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            var root = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            var mainPage = root.Content as MainPage;
            if (mainPage != null && args is FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs)
            {
                mainPage.ContinueFileOpenPicker(args as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs);
            }
        }
```

Put this code in app.xaml.cs it will work..